# C# Web Browser Message Box - Copy The Alert text

Tags: c#, browser, alerts

i want to make an program using web browser
so i have make Account Password Changer( for an game website)
when i click change password it will change it but i dont sure
its will show a alert it the web browser the password has been changed or the old pass is invalid etc
i want to copy the alert text to know it changed or now
any one can help me
?

Comment: Windows Forms or WPF? Mentioning C# does not help to solve your question in any way as IE's API is language-neutral COM.

Comment: @sheng-jiang Windows Forms
(its not program its a plugin for application )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Windows Forms's webbrowser class, [Implement IDocHostShowUI on your webbrowser site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/8b0712ca-0b92-4e3d-a243-27af57a57213/).

If you are using the wrapper class generated by aximp, [Implement IDocHostShowUI on the container's IOleClientSite implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control).

The text will be passed to you when the control is calling the IDocHostShowUI::ShowMessage Method

Comment: `code            MyWebBrowser Webb = new MyWebBrowser();
            Webb.DocumentText = @"<html><head><body><script language='JScript'>alert(""Test Only"")</script></body></head></html>";
            Webb.ShowMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("New Alert = " + e.Result);
            };`                                                                          

 
i have test and it working but cannot get the text of the alert and it show New Alert =
without the text

Comment: You are using the control without a container, this is not supported. Also setting document text is an asycn operation, you need to wait for the DocumentCompleted event and pump messages in the current thread. How is this ShowMessage raised? It should have something like DocHostShowUIShowMessageEvent.SetParameters(hwnd, lpstrText, lpstrCaption, dwType, lpstrHelpFile, dwHelpContext, lpResult); to save the data in the event argument before raising the event